# Using ViewModel with multiple Models in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, automapper, asp.net-mvc-viewmodel

I use the following approach when creating a ViewModel with multiple models (entities) in ASP.NET MVC:

Student **Entity:**

```
public class Student
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Surname { get; set; } 

    //Foreign key for Country
    public int CountryId { get; set; }

    public virtual Country Country { get; set; }
}
```

Country **Entity:**

```
public class Country
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Student> Students { get; set; }
}
```

Student **ViewModel:**

```
public class StudentViewModel
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Surname { get; set; } 

    //Foreign key for Country
    public int CountryId { get; set; }

    public virtual Country Country { get; set; }
}
```

Country **ViewModel:**

```
public class CountryViewModel
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    //??? Should I use Student entity or StudentViewModel at here >>>
    public virtual ICollection<Student> Students { get; set; }
}
```

At this stage, I am not sure if I should add the entities or ViewModels of the related model in the ViewModel. I use Automapper and map entity and viewmodels, but I do not want to map each properties as shown below and want to merge models in the ViewModel classess...

```
CreateMap<Student, StudentViewModel>()
   .ForMember(dest => ...)
   .ForMember(dest => ...)
   .ForMember(dest => ...)
```

So, could you pls clarify me how to merge multiple entities in viewmodel properly?

Comment: That is quite easy , hope this will help you.
  .ForMember(vm => vm.Name, map => map.MapFrom(model => model.Name))

Comment: Use a StudentViewModel in your CountryViewModel and a CountryViewModel  in your StudentViewModel . Setup 2 mappings (Country -> CountryViewModel and Student -> StudentViewModel). Automapper is smart enough to map the children without the need of `ForMember`.

Comment: @AsifRaza Do you mean that there is no need to use Navigation properties in the ViewModels and necessary entity properties and models can be inferred via AutoMapper? Could you pls. explain a little bit more?

Comment: @SteveGreene Thanks for reply. I think there are 2 ways to solve this problem. **1)** Adding viewmodel to the related ViewModels (in this example we should add CountryViewModel (not Country entity) to StudentViewModel and vice versa). We should not add entity classes to Viewmodel. **2)** Using only AutoMapper (not adding any viewmodel to another viewmodel)  and define necessary properties by merging entity and viewmodels. Is that true???

Comment: In general, compose viewmodels. If it were me, I wouldn't have a CountryViewModel - I would just flatten it into the StudentViewModel (i.e. I would have a CountryName property in the StudentViewModel. You shouldn't need to add a bunch of ForMember clauses. That is the purpose of Automapper.

Comment: @SteveGreene If I did not misunderstood, you meant that (for this scenario) I should not include Country entity or CountryViewModel in StudentViewModel and instead of this I add a CountryName property to the StudentViewModel and then map Name property of the Country entity to this CountryName property. By doing this, we include necessary properties instead of the entire entity or viewmodel. **Is these all true**???

Comment: Yes. Think of a view model as what is needed to compose your view. It will obviously consist of various entities and possibly some other non-entity properties needed to build the view. So in your GET methods you will load a viewmodel and in the POST you will reverse the process to update the entity. Put your validation in the VM. Lots of articles out here on the topic.

Comment: Thanks a lot... In this case, which one would you suggest? **#** Including necessary ViewModel to the ViewModel that to be used or **#** Using AutoMapper and including only the necessary properties by using AutoMapper's config instead of the previous option?